# HTTP request uuid or request start time in Ruby applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, request, timestamp, uuid

I need to get a request uuid or time when server get a request. It's easy in Rails, but I'm working on a gem and I would like it to be more generic. So I would like it to work also with Sinatra and every other Ruby application which works in a http server.

This is another problem, it's a gem. I can't put `Time.now` at the beggining of my application controller. I need it to be generic, so it should work with different frameworks.

What would you propose?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a Rack middleware which you can use independently from your actual application framework (as long as it used rack, which is true for at least Rails, Sinatra, Padriono and most other Ruby web frameworks).

Rails already includes a middleware for adding a unique ID to a request of required in [ActionDispatch::RequestId](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.0/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb). Another alternative could be the [rack-request-id gem](https://github.com/anveo/rack-request-id).

A minimal versions of this midleware could look like this:

```
class RequestIdMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    env['request_id'] = env['HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID'] || SecureRandom.uuid
    env['request_started_at'] = Time.now

    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

You can then use this middleware in your `config.ru` or by adding this to your `application.rb` in Rails:

```
config.middleware.use RequestIdMiddleware
```

Comment: But can I use it in a gem without intrusion in Rails / Sinatra app? Not every user has `config.ru`, and in Rails I should use `config.middleware.use`, in Sinatra `use`, what about other frameworks? Is there a generic solution?

Comment: Every framework that uses rack (which as I said is about any web framework in ruby) can use additional rack middlewares. In fact, most of the default features of rack are provided by several middleware classes in rack itself. Thus, a rack middleware **is** the generic solution. How the middleware is then setup in the actual framework differs, but all frameworks can use it in the end.